# SQL query refinement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that usually takes about 15 minutes to run, and im trying to see if I am missing something to refine this and get it running faster. Any help would be appreciated.

Both tables, enterprise and AD have roughly 2000 unique records. Running this on a 2k8r2 server, 8gb ram, 2 vcpu, sql 2k8r2.

```
select
    distinct dnsname,
    description,
    os,
    role,
    lastlogontimestamp
from
    [dbo].[ActiveDirectory]
    where AD_PULL_DATE = '4/2/2013'
    and role in ('DELEGATE',
                'NO_PWDREQD',
                'ENABLED',
                'NO_PWDEXP')
    and dnsname not in (select distinct dnsname from Enterprise)
```

Comment: What happens if you both DISTINCT? You don't need it for the IN clause and it works across the row, not just for dnsname. And what indexes do you have please?

Comment: Both tables have roughly 2000 unique dnsnames, but there are tons of records per dnsname. currently none of the tables are indexed, im guessing that is what i should do first? index the dnsname column?

Comment: it will help, but you need others too. No indexes at all? really?